# Prevent Shorewall log entries for specific IP address and/or port

Tags: firewall, logging, port, shorewall

I have Shorewall firewall setup on a Debian server which is working fine. I get various log entries in /var/log/messages when packets are dropped, as expected, for example:

```
Aug 17 19:09:07 cheetah kernel: [80026654.168568] Shorewall:net2all:DROP:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:48:8a:5c:cc:00:04:4d:de:18:c2:08:00 SRC=123.123.123.123 DST=111.111.111.111 LEN=500 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=24371 PROTO=UDP SPT=500 DPT=500 LEN=480
```

I don't have any services on my server listening on port 500. There are plenty of other entries like this as well with other destination ports from people doing port scans, etc (e.g., people trying to connect to RDP on 3389, etc)

My question is, how would I go about preventing these dropped packets from being logged? Google is not providing any help and I can't find anything about that on Shorewall's web site either. I understand that it's important to log them so I know what's hitting my system, but I'm also curious how I would prevent the logging if I wanted to. Specifically how would I prevent logging for a specific IP address AND/OR port only (e.g., prevent logging for all dropped packets from a given IP, or prevent logging for all dropped packets attempting to connect to a specific port).

The answer may be to just put an explicit DROP rule into /etc/shorewall/rules which I'm considering (and I assume that since a rule would be matched that no logging would occur), but I wanted to investigate my options here first to see what everyone thinks.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I believe your assumption is correct. Explicit DROP rules that shadow policies should suppress logging of packets dropped by policy.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rule:

```
DROP      123.123.123.123       111.111.111.111      udp      500
```

or specified the 'blacklist' option in `/etc/shorewall/interfaces`, and put the below lines into `/etc/shorewall/blacklist`:

```
123.123.123.123                       udp             500
```

Also review the BLACKLIST_LOGLEVEL in `/etc/shorewall/shorewall.conf`.

Comment: OK, this is the solution I suspected -- basically add a rule to drop the packets or blacklist them, which in turn results in no logging.

So is there a way other than this to just prevent logging of certain packets (i.e., if no rule was added to explicitly drop them, and I just want to skip logging for them)?